# How to logon a user on a server and run a process given a Kerberos Ticket

Tags: ssh, kerberos, windows-authentication, gssapi, sspi

How does authentication and logon work on Windows with Kerberos? What I want to achieve is to logon a user on a server and run a process for that user.

As a first step, I create a Kerberos ticket on the client and send it to the server. On the server, I do not know the API to logon the user given its ticket.
Of course I can accept the security context using AcceptSecurityContext (SSPI), but that does not initiate a logon.

I think that some SSH implementations for Windows do exactly that. But I want to know how and what API they probably use?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you can do this. You do need to call `AcceptSecurityContext` on the ticket to get a security context. This is what bootstraps everything in Windows. From there you can do a couple different things.

Usually you call `ImpersonateSecurityContext` so the current thread understands what user it thinks it needs to be. After that you can call `QuerySecurityContextToken` to get a Windows access token handle. With this handle you then call `CreateProcessAsUser`. You can also tell it to do things like load the profile if necessary.

This doesn't really do a logon like `LogonUserX` does, but it effectively starts a process as that user, which is usually what people are looking to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works so far with `CreateProcessAsUser`, a new process is started running as user. However, it cannot communicate with other services on different servers (e.g. a REST API). It is not possible to create new tickets for other services (using `AquireCredentialsHandle` and `InitializeSecurityContext`), I get an error: "No credentials are available in the security package".
I can create new tickets (delegation) in the service after `ImpersonateSecurityContext` and before I create a new process. But that is not what I want. Is it possible to do it in the new process?

Comment: Yeah, there's one more step required in that scenario, which is to configure the account the parent process is running as to allow delegation and impersonation. So `client => server => child process` that means the `server` process is running as a user and that user must have impersonate and delegate configured.

Comment: It seems to work with unconstrained delegation. Do you know whether this approach works with constrained delegation (where the TGT is not sent along with the service ticket for delegation purposes).

Comment: @Steve Could you let me know how to get the hToken value from security context. We are trying to create a process in `spring controller` method where we wont be having scope of `AuthorizationHeader` to extract the `authorizationHeader.getTokenBytes()` . We have been spending more than a week, but no luck. any small hint would be great help! TIA!